# Command remove Zend Framework 1 of centos 6

Tags: linux, zend-framework, zend-framework2, centos

I've got zf1 on my server but i'd like to uninstall it. How can i **uninstall ZF1 off my Linux server (CentOs6)**?

I just wanted to remove it completely. 
Because i need to install ZF2 instead.

Thank you

Comment: You use ZF2 on a per project basis. To remove the ZF1 library, simply delete your zf1 folder.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed Zend Framework via **yum** utility after adding an external repo. as described in this [tutorial](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/install-zend-framework-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/)

so you can uninstall it using

```
# yum remove php-ZendFramework
```

Note: Try to use tab to get the correct package name if yum did not find this package.